# RETAG: All cs.XYZ.ABC to XYZ.ABC

Tags: status-completed, retag-request

I think this proposal has enough support [here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/118). Since this is the template for requesting RETAGs, I thought I'll just make this thread for all of them.

While we're at it, can we also do math.ct.category-theory -> ct.category-theory

Comment: Arghh. I did a few and then ran out of steam. Will do some more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've created synonyms for the above, as well as replacing math.ct.category-theory. Since they are synonyms, old tags might stay around for a while. I didn't want to do merges because that messes up the ordering on the front page. There aren't very many posts with these tags in any case, so it shouldn't create a big problem.

Comment: Having a synonym A -> B, plenty of questions with tag A, and no questions with tag B seems very confusing to me. What's the problem with merging tags? How does it affect the ordering on the front page if you use moderator tools to merge tags?

Comment: Regarding the confusion: for example, http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/cs.dc.distributed-comp/info now redirects to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/dc.distributed-comp/info which gives a "Page Not Found" error. We can't see tag info, we can't see the place where we could propose new tag synonyms. Besides, when regular users try to suggest tag synonyms, the system requires that the target tag has more questions than the source tag; hence we should make sure that our top-level tags have *plenty* of questions already, to make things work smoothly.

Comment: all of this is true. and in general, tag synonyms are decided by votes. but we haven't had enough hi-rep people to do that.

Comment: Well, if it's true, why don't you merge tags instead of merely creating synonyms?-)

Comment: two reasons. Firstly, as a moderator, I want to get out of the business of managing tag synonyms since that should be a community driven process. Secondly, to merge A into a non-existent B, I have to change at least one A to a B, and that unnecessarily promotes the question to the top of the front page, something I am loathe to do. But if people don't mind old questions popping up, I can do the merges.

Comment: @Suresh: I understand the first point, but I guess that the second point can be worked around (tediously) by creating a dummy question with desired tags and deleting it immediately.

Comment: FYI, right now if you try to ask a question with tag [cs.X.Y] such that there are already questions tagged [cs.X.Y] but none tagged [X.Y], and you don't have enough rep to create tags, you get told that you're not allowed to create [X.Y].  This is off-putting to new users.

Comment: Ah ok. Actually I have a dummy post for this purpose. I'll do this tonight

Answer (score 1):

These are is still missing: cs.fl.formal-languages, cs.ne.neural-evol.

Comment: this is now done.

Comment: Great, many thanks!