# Merge game-theory and cs.gt.game-theory to gt.game-theory

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please merge the tags [game-theory] and [cs.gt.game-theory] into a tag [gt.game-theory], which does not currently exist.

Related: [RETAG: All cs.XYZ.ABC to XYZ.ABC](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/retag-all-cs-xyz-abc-to-xyz-abc)

Comment: I'm confused. there appear to be 4 gt.game-theory posts and none of the other two

Comment: @Suresh: The situation changed after I posted this request.  Daniel Apon seems to have replaced [game-theory] and [cs.gt.game-theory] by [gt.game-theory] manually (thanks, Daniel!).  The remaining task is to convert the former two tags to tag synonyms to [gt.game-theory].

Comment: that has been done.

Comment: @Suresh: Can you please add the [status-completed] tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that shortly after this request was posted, Daniel Apon replaced existing [game-theory] and [cs.gt.game-theory] by [gt.game-theory] manually.  Suresh Venkat created tag synonyms.  Thanks, Daniel and Suresh!