# Deleting Your Own Question

Tags: discussion

I imagine it's often a good idea to delete a closed question or perhaps a heavily down-voted one.  But are there any other circumstances in which it's good to delete your own question?

The reason I ask is because I noticed the "disciplined" badge and am now confused because I don't see how that's disciplined.  Perhaps this is for questions that are up-voted but then turn out to be wrong?

Comment: On SO, disciplined is usually earned for deleting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a matter of cleanup, since closed questions remain on the list. If you realize that your question doesn't make sense or is a duplicate, and then delete it, that helps remove clutter.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get this badge for deleting your own *answer* to someone else's question. The badge description uses the ambiguous "your own 'post'". Thought I'd clarify.

I got this badge because one of the questions became a community wiki and I was asked to split my answer into four separate answers.