# Places to look for articles and discussions

Tags: discussion

*In accordance with [this](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/developing-a-cw-policy/63#63), I'm asking this question here.*

So, I've recently found a social network for scientists, and would like to know, if there are more such networks, where scientists and phd-students discuss their articles and thesises.

Comment: I didn't think there was any need to make this CW. But I don't think you can reverse it at this point

Comment: There are many science blogs and some mailing lists where discussion takes place.  But overall I think there is more science done person-to-person via email, Skype, and face-to-face discussion, than is done on Internet-mediated social networks.  How do you define a social network?

Answer (score 1):

The [Computing Resource Repository](http://arxiv.org/corr/home) has many papers before they are published.