# Are discussions about the field of TCS off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This has been raised several times and we should make a group decision.  Raised before:

- [Developing a CW policy.](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/developing-a-cw-policy/63#63)
- [Are list questions such as about conferences on-topic?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-list-questions-such-as-about-conferences-on-topic/66#66)
- [Places to look for articles and discussions](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99/places-to-look-for-articles-and-discussions)

Are questions about the field of TCS on or off topic?  Examples would be lists of books, journals, or conferences.

Assuming that they're off-topic, Robert Cartaino has already stated that these questions should not be posted on meta (even though there was some community support for the idea):

> Because it is off-topic against the
>   purpose of the site. There's already a
>   wide-spread belief that if something
>   is off topic, you just make it
>   community wiki. You don't need to add
>   another layer to that.

So we need to determine:

1. Are questions about the field really off-topic?
2. If they are off-topic, does that mean that they can't be asked on meta?

These decisions should go into our FAQ.

Answer (score 9):

Questions about the field are certainly not off topic. I'm also not in favor of making them meta. I think we will have to live with them on the main site, enforce CW and (maybe) big-list and soft-question tags, and let people who don't like them use tagging to exclude them (this is what I've done on MO, with the soft-question tag)

Comment: This seems like a great solution to me.