# Existence of two lists of FAQs is confusing

Tags: discussion

Now that [one problem](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/823/should-we-put-the-phrase-research-level-in-our-general-faq) of the page [cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) has been resolved, we would like to discuss another: namely, the existence of two lists of FAQs is confusing.

- [cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) (which I call “FAQ on main” here)
- [Official FAQ for Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science) on the meta site (which I call “FAQ on meta” here)

(I am not talking about the [FAQ *about* meta](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/faq), which serves a different purpose.)

I hope that the new text on the FAQ on main reduces the problem of having two lists by listing some of the most important entries in the FAQ on meta.  Still, I cannot help imagining that both pages are claiming *I am the official one!  I am more important than the other list!  Read me first!*, which I do not like.

Note that the moderators cannot edit everything on the FAQ on main, although they can edit certain parts of it.  In a discussion which happened in comments on [this post](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/823/should-we-put-the-phrase-research-level-in-our-general-faq/927#927), Suresh (Feb 4 at 16:22) has suggested merging the FAQ on meta to the FAQ on main by putting everything before the section “What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?” (if I understand it correctly).  I am not sure if that is the best way.

*Update: It turned out that Suresh’s suggestion was something different.  See the comment.*

Other solutions may be:

1. Include the links of all *questions* in the FAQ on meta in the FAQ on main as an itemized list.
2. Leave the FAQ page on main as is now, and rename the FAQ on meta to something along “Supplemental FAQ for Theoretical Computer Science.”

What do you think?

Comment: Option (1) is what I intended to suggest.

Answer (score 3):

For #1, perhaps the page itself could query meta and list all questions tagged [faq]?

This is something we could add to the code, and it would be much simpler than manually doing it yourselves.

(However, I wonder about the value of a "quick read" /faq which is a giant list of hyperlinks..)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. But you're right that the code wouldn't necessarily know how to order the questions or even format them in some organized fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately that would not be useful for the current cstheory.stackexchange.com because most entries in the FAQ on meta are just _answers_ to a [single large question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science) (which I do not like).

Comment: we can refactor that.

Comment: You can also link to answers of that one FAQ question, so that should not be a problem.