# Are question asking for resource recommendation on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have [seen](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20086/20866) that questions asking for book recommendation are considered to be okay/on-topic on this site.

Is the same stance adopted for other sorts of resource recommendations?

If so, why are such questions considered on-topic on this site?

Comment: there are certain standout refs that are widely regarded as high quality ie widespread consensus among many in the field & the lists capture them.

Answer (score 1):

There has been questions about similar resources like videos: [What videos should everybody watch?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/what-videos-should-everybody-watch) but they are very very infrequent.

Soft questions are considered a gray area in the scope and need way more care in asking.

See [soft-question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) tag, [good subjective, bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), and [Is my question suitable for cstheory?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2662/)